# Suppose $f_1,f_2$ entire functions. Produce entire $h,g_1,g_2$ such that $f_1=hg_1$ and $f_2=hg_2$ with $g_1,g_2$ no common zeros.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, weierstrass-factorization

Suppose $f_1,f_2$ entire functions. Produce entire $h,g_1,g_2$ such that $f_1=hg_1$ and $f_2=hg_2$ with $g_1,g_2$ no common zeros.

I know I have to use Weierstrass factorization theorem somehow but I’m not sure how.

Comment: №3 https://math.ucsd.edu/~doprea/220w21/sol2.pdf

Comment: thank you so much it was way easier  than expected